# Encoding for characters in C#

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, windows-console

I'm studying alone from a book. In the book it is said that I can use all symbols that are in the [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) table (although it is not explained very well). But somehow I can't do it. Here is the code that I test:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            char a = '\u2605';
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
}
```

The code should print a star, but the output is

> "   E"

Can you tell me how I can use any symbol from the table with no problems?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the console you're using doesn't really support full Unicode. It's *not* a C# issue here - it's a matter of persuading the console to do what you want :( If you show the same character via `MessageBox.Show`, it's fine.

Comment: Yes, I tried to make a WPF application and everything is ok with it.

Comment: the problem is probably with the font of the console that does not support those gyphs

Answer (score 3):

It is [Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2605/index.htm) encoding you are looking for:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
```

As mentioned, it will only work if the console supports Unicode. Also, the font used also needs to support the Unicode characters in order to display them. For instance, `Lucida Console` does *not* support `U+2605`, but it [does support other characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/lucida_console/list.htm).

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
char a = '\u2191';
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

The above code will print an upwards arrow in my console using either [Consolas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolas), [Lucida Console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucida#Lucida_Console) or `Raster Fonts`.

Comment: Well only if the console *actually* supports that. (It doesn't work on mine, for example.)

Comment: LINQPAD throws an `IOException` with `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` but compiles fine with `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode`. Using unicode, a black star is printed correctly.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: I'd expect it to *compile* correctly either way. And what works on LINQPad may well not work everywhere...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that but there is exception: Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I realize that this is an issue with the output method, I'm merely sharing my results with the LINQPad output. Edit: Looks like it does compile, but an `IOException` is thrown at runtime. Still getting used to LP, I guess ;)

Comment: @user2972343: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419518/the-parameter-is-incorrect-when-setting-unicode-as-console-encoding) out, it might explain why you get an `IOException` (because the console does not support unicode). I do not get this exception when running on VS 2012 and Windows 8 however (just getting a square printed out).

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. By the way, I'm using VS 2010 on Windows 32-bit.

Comment: Well, this example is for writing in file. But what if I want to output the symbol in the console?

Comment: @user2972343: The font used in the console also needs to support the characters in order to display them. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score -4):

I'm pretty sure you need to convert your char to string first, try

```
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
```

Comment: Because it's wrong - it's as simple as that. `Console.WriteLine(char)` is perfectly valid.